# Flutter: *** 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, share, appdelegate

I am pretty new to coding, but working on a flutter app and trying to integrate the ability to share images to Instagram Stories using the [Social Share](https://pub.dev/packages/social_share) package. Everything works fine to generate the photo and the dynamic link (can test by commenting out the SocialShare part), but when the app tried to open Instagram on iOS I am getting the following error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
```

Image is generated using

```
final newImage = await _socialShareService.sharedImage();

//then image is saved to Firebase and dynamic link generated
final postsUpdateData = createPostsRecordData(
     sharedImage: newImage);
await containerPostsRecord.reference.update(
      postsUpdateData);

var uri = await _dynamicLinkService
      .createDynamicLink()
print(uri.toString());

//this is where the error is occurring
await SocialShare.shareInstagramStory(newImage,
       backgroundBottomColor: "#000000",
       backgroundTopColor: "#ffffff",
       attributionURL: uri.toString());
```

I am having trouble understanding the error to figure out what is being called on nil. Full error message is below

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x180e350fc 0x199685d64 0x180f3e564 0x180f496e0 0x180df2514 0x180e10ebc 0x101d6c0a4 0x10507a75c 0x104bb3cf8 0x104f41bb4 0x104e691c0 0x104e6cf24 0x180e4a318 0x180dcecf0 0x180dc94ec 0x180da7d08 0x180dbb468 0x19c95f38c 0x18375e5d0 0x1834dcf74 0x100a1fb68 0x101589aa4)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00000001b84f7964 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
->  0x1b84f7964 <+8>:  b.lo   0x1b84f7984               ; <+40>
    0x1b84f7968 <+12>: pacibsp 
    0x1b84f796c <+16>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x1b84f7970 <+20>: mov    x29, sp
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
```

I know the error is coming from the AppDelegate.swift function, but I am not sure exactly how to solve this. Any insight is greatly appreciated!

UPDATED: Info.plist does include facebook and instagram.

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>name</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fbauth</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
        <string>instagram-stories</string>
        <string>facebook-stories</string>
        <string>facebook</string>
        <string>instagram</string>
        <string>twitter</string>
        <string>whatsapp</string>
    </array>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you add this part to info.plist?

iOS Configuration 
Add this to your Info.plist to use share on instagram and facebook story
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
 <string>instagram-stories</string>
 <string>facebook-stories</string>
 <string>facebook</string>
 <string>instagram</string>
 <string>twitter</string>
 <string>whatsapp</string>
    <string>tg</string>
 </array>

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar thanks for your comment. I do have those items in my info.plist and have updated my question to reflect that. It clearly has something to do with the keys, but I just cannot figure out what.

Comment: Can you share your info plist pic? and what is your "newImage" value content?
check te example https://pub.dev/packages/social_share
 SocialShare.shareInstagramStory(
                        "file.path",

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar 'newImage' is a custom function I have written that generates a watermarked image and returns a url string to the image within my Firebase database. I followed the example, but am obviously missing something. 'file.path' is just a url string, correct? And I will add an image of that section of my info.plist.

Comment: file.path is not url it's a path in local app.

Comment: Oh that may be it then! I will work on that now, and thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar that worked! Thank you so much, and in hindsight it makes sense that it was a file path and not a url path.